# How to change borderRight color of Material UI drawer?

Tags: reactjs

I have a drawer from the material UI core. I have a background but it's displaying a white border on the right. How can I get rid of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use **borderRight={1}** in conjunction with **borderColor="value"** attribute, as described in the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/system/borders/). Those properties can be applied to any element.

Example:

```
<Box borderRight={1} borderColor="red">
```